# show web page notification in specific place

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, notifications

How to show notifications in a web page in specific place with specific icons (desktop: Chrome, Mozilla)? - like the header here in stackoverflow.
Have been reading about Mozilla Push API and Google's service but couldn't find how to costomize it. Have my own backend (node JS).

Comment: The display location of push notification is not customizable. Maybe try JavaScript implementations like [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)?

Comment: 10XS. The demo let you choose place in the page (left/right/etc.) How can I connect it with an html element such as div or <li class="header-notification">